# Is this hack a defined behavior for T4

Tags: .net, visual-studio, t4, undefined-behavior, forward-compatibility

I recently set out on an expedition to unit-test a rather complex T4 class. I've arrived at a major breakthough, but I'm afraid the observed behavior may only be coincidental(ie, may break in future versions of Visual Studio)

I basically have something like this:

MainTemplate.tt:

```
<#@ include file="generator.tt.cs" #>
```

And then in generator.tt.cs I have

```
//<#+
class code
{
....
}
//#>
```

The observed behavior of this is that I can both use the declared classes and such from the T4 template AND compile the code file as normal. However, is prefixing a comment before the `<#+` and `#>` tags at all defined behavior? Do I risk this breaking in the future?

Also, I've tested this on both MonoDevelop and Visual Studio 2012. It appears to work for both. Visual Studio 2008 compatibility isn't important for me though.

Comment: I think this is interesting. As for breaking in future versions AFAIK you use backslash for disabling a T4 tag (ie \<# or \#>). // comments means nothing to T4 right now AFAIK and I think it's reasonable to assume it will stay that way. But obviously I am not a person that can give such guarantees.

Comment: The comment characters you're using to hide the opening <#+ will end up in your final output template.  I guess that seems likely to be tolerable if you're generating C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say we won't 'ever' break things in future, but I find it hard to imagine what we'd do that would break this.  Comments inside the feature block will always be respected and comments before it need to be respected to allow generation of comments.  I think you are safe.

You'd have to use fully-qualified names in the generator.tt.cs file I think, as there'd be nowhere to put using statements or namespaces.

How does this compare for you to precompiling the helper library for your tests via some empty stub template and then testing the precompiled version?

Comment: I can avoid fully qualified names by using `#if NOT_IN_T4` or similar and having it conditionally include a namespace and having the `using` statements *inside* the namespace declaration, rather than the usual outside. You can see my actual source code [here](https://bitbucket.org/earlz/barelymvc/src/d12cf46bdc26/BarelyMVC/ViewEngine/ViewEngineInternal.tt.cs?at=ViewEngineOverhaul)

Comment: Oooh wow, just read your profile to realize you are responsible for T4. I guess that's the official answer then :) As for the precompiled stub template thing, I don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: Well, as official as statements of potential future comnpatibility get ;-)
As to the precompiled stub, if you are pulling in a helper library to a real template, you could equally pull in the same helper code to a precomiled or runtime (equivalent names) template, which will generate a code file which would contain your helpers as nested classes rather than the result of running the template.

That would build as part of your application naturally.